How to expand and shrink views inside of a horizontal scrollview without affecting the frame of the parent HStack in SwiftUI
In swiftui, I have horizontal scrollview which has one hstack containing three different view but the 2nd view has variable height, when the user clicks on this view, I am toggling two variables namely
showExchangeRates.toggle()
                        

showExpand.toggle()

I am also having these modifier at the end of the horizontal scroll view to give each view the mimic of swipable view, as each of the view is taking full screen width so the second view only appears after user swipes from right to left
.contentMargins(.horizontal, 8, for: .scrollContent)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)

so when the user is on second view and the frame height of 2nd view is expanded by clicking on it, now when the user goes back to the first view(without clicking again on the second view to get it back to its normal height), the first view is taking too much height because probably the 2nd view changed the height of the whole hstack which all views are in. I have tried togging these variables using onappear and on disappear on both first and the second view but that isn't working probably because SwiftUI is considering all the three view inside of the Hstack as appeared or maybe I don't know the reason behind it.
VStack {
            Text("This")
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                
            
            HStack {

                // Start of Currency Rate Card
                
                swipeTotalMarket()
                
                cryptoTab()
                
                metalRates()
                
            }//HStack
            .scrollTargetLayout()
            //
            
            
            
        }//scrollview(horizontal) Card Group 2
        
        .contentMargins(.horizontal, 8, for: .scrollContent)
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        Text("That")
    }

I have tried using the draggesture in swiftui to toggle the variables when it senses a swipe kind of behavious,
.gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: percentWidth(percent: 1.3), coordinateSpace: .local)
                .onChanged { value in
                    if value.translation.width > 14 { // Check if the swipe is from left to right
                        showExchangeRates = false
                        showExpand = false
                    }}
        )

it does work but is not consistent and not the best solution.
PS: The HStack is necessary in a horizontal scrollview in this case.
